# C struct with function pointer as member and variable pointer as member

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, member

Could someone explain to me why the "manipulation" done to the structure in the `play` function "remains" in the `main` function ? I thought it was limited to the scope of the function `play`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Alpha{
    void (*ptr_f)(void);
    int *a;
};

void hello(void){
    printf("Hello\n");
}

void play(struct Alpha *Data, void (*func_ptr)(void), int *test){
    Data->ptr_f = func_ptr;
    Data->a = test;
}

int main(void){
    int data1 = 4;
    struct Alpha Test;

    play(&Test, hello, &data1);
    Test.ptr_f();
    printf("*(Test.a) = %d\n", *(Test.a));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I see it, you passed a pointer, so because the same memory address is accessed, it is not a scoped based modification. So the 'play' function takes a pointer to the 'struct Alpha' as an argument. When you pass the address of the 'struct Alpha' variable 'Test' to the 'play' function using the '&' operator, you are effectively passing a reference to the original 'struct Alpha'  variable. Since 'Data' points to the same memory location as 'Test' in the 'main' fuction, any modifications made to the members of 'Data' inside the 'play' function will affect the original 'Test'

Comment: To have the modification done by `play` only be local to that function, it would need to get a **copy** of the structure, i.e. `void play(struct Alpha Data, void (*func_ptr)(void), int *test){ Data.ptr_f = ...`.

Comment: Learn what pointers are.  You seem to think that taking the address of an object causes that object to be copied.  It doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

Your program boils down to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Foo(int* p)
{
  *p = 42;
}

int main()
{
  int bar = 1;
  Foo(&bar);
  printf("%d\n", bar);
  return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is `42`.

- in `Foo(&bar);` you pass the address of `bar` to the `Foo` function.
- therefore the `Foo` function the `p` parameter points to the `bar` variable.
- and therefore as soon as you modify `*p` in `Foo` it actually modifies `bar`.

This is how pointers work in C, and this should be explained at the beginning of the chapter dealing with pointers in your C text book.

Answer (score 2):

Function arguments in C are passed by value, meaning a 'copy' of the value is passed to the function itself.

On your call: `play(&Test, hello, &data1);` you pass `Test`'s **address**, meaning you're giving a copy of the **place** in memory that the struct is saved.

Inside `play` you then use the arrow operator `->` which dereference addresses. So you're actually going inside that place in the memory, modifying what is in there. From the moment you used that operator, it will be affecting the original structure, unrelated to scope.

I like to think of it as if someone gave you an address of a house ('copy' of the address), and then you would go inside there and move a furniture, it would actually be moved.

Comment: I like the **reference** xD

Answer (score 0):

In the given code, the modification made in the play function remains visible in the main function because the play function takes a **pointer** to the struct Alpha as an argument. When you pass the address of the struct Alpha variable Test to the play function using the **&** (address of) operator (play(&Test, hello, &data1);), you are effectively **passing a reference** to the original struct Alpha variable.

Inside the play function, the line `Data->ptr_f = func_ptr;`
assigns the value of func_ptr to the ptr_f member of the struct Alpha pointed to by Data. Similarly, `Data->a = test`; assigns the value of test to the a member of the struct Alpha pointed to by Data.

Since Data points to the **same memory location** as Test in the main function, any modifications made to the members of Data inside the play function will affect the original Test variable in the main function. Therefore, when you call `Test.ptr_f();` and `*(Test.a)`, you are accessing the modified values of ptr_f and a that were assigned inside the play function.

> This is how the modification in the play function remains visible in
> the main function.